# How do I test that a RuntimeError is using string interpolation correctly in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, error-handling, rspec

I have a method which records a change to a particular record in my database, but first, it checks to category type for validity before going any further. If this returns false, an error is raised.

```
class UpgradePackageRecorder

  CATEGORIES = [ an array of categories here ... ]

  def initialize(category)
    @category = category
  end

  def record_change
    unless valid_category?
      raise "#{category} is not a recognized category"
    end

    other_methods
  end

  private

  def valid_category?
    CATEGORIES.include?(category)
  end

end
```

I began writing an rspec test for this to verify that the error was being raised properly. Here is the test case:

```
RSpec.describe UpgradePackageRecorder do
  describe '#record_change' do
    context 'the package type is invalid' do
      it 'raises an error' do

       recorder = UpgradePackageRecorder.new('Bronze')

       expect { recorder.record_change }.to raise_error(RuntimeError, /bronze is not a recognized category/)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I ran the test I got this error:

```
Failure/Error: raise "#{category} is not a recognized category"

RuntimeError:
  bronze is not a recognized category
```

Why is the string interpolation showing up like this? I also tried it like
`category + ' is not a recognized category` but that did not fix the issue.

To make this even more confusing, I took the string interpolation out and still saw the issue:

```
Failure/Error: raise "Unrecognized category"

RuntimeError:
  Unrecognized category
```

Comment: it looks like the error is not getting intercepted by `expect { change }` ... can you show the model callbacks (how `valid_category?` is called) and the whole rspec caseq

Comment: Yes, need a [mcve]

Comment: I updated with more thorough examples.

Comment: `Bronze` and `bronze` are not the same. And what' about `CATEGORIES`? May be problem is that array includes your category?

Comment: @mechnicov I forgot to include that I have a method in UpgradePackageRecorder that downcases all the categories when they get there. Also, I double checked that the categories array does not include 'bronze'.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

The syntax that ended up working for me was this:

```
it 'raises an error' do

  expect do
    UpgradePackageRecorder.new(
      'Bronze'
    ).record_change
  end.to raise_error(
    RuntimeError, /bronze is not a recognized category/
  )

end
```

Also, I had another `expect` in the same `it` block that I removed. It was verifying whether the `record_change` method went on to create a certain object.

Comment: "It was verifying whether the record_change method went on to create a certain object." - well, _that_ was the problem, not the curly brace vs do/end. Regardless, good job figuring this out.

Comment: You should probably separate the tests, so `subject { described_class.new('Bronze') }` can be put at the context level, and then you can spec different things on the same object, in separate `it` blocks.